# Get the lat/long coordinates of a marker inside a PanoramaView

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

According to the Google Maps iOS SDK, I instanciate my panoramaView like this :

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class DemoViewController: UIViewController,GMSPanoramaViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let panoramaNear = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.059139, -122.958391)

    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView.panoramaWithFrame(CGRectZero,
        nearCoordinate:panoramaNear)

    self.view = panoView;
  }
}
```

When I tap on the panoramaView, I'd like to get the latitude and longitude I just tapped.

This delegate method is what I need

```
- (void) panoramaView:      (GMSPanoramaView *)     panoramaView
didTap:         (CGPoint)   point
```

I'm stucked with the last part which is to convert this CGPoint into a CLLocation2DCoordinates ! I don't need the pitch, heading etc... I need the lat/long tuple.

Is there a way to handle these locations or this is just not possible in a panoramaView ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CGPoint is not in any way linked to CLLocationCoordinate2D.
A CGPoint refers to a point (x,y) in a given rectangle, probably a CGRect that is defined by a certain CGSize.

You can not access a CLLocationCoordinate2D through the object defined in this delegate method.

You do get a CLLocationCoordinate2D through:

- `- (void)panoramaView:GMSPanoramaView *)view didMoveToPanorama:(GMSPanorama *)panorama nearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate` and
- `- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view error:(NSError *)error onMoveNearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate`